# Evaluate $ \int_0^a\int_x^a\frac{y^2\,dy\,dx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ by changing order of integration

Tags: integration

**The question is:**

*By changing the order of integration in the integral* $I = \int_0^a\int_x^a\frac{y^2\,dy\,dx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ *show that* $I=\frac{1}{3}a^3\,\ln(1+\sqrt{2})$

**My attempt so far:**

So, swapping the order of integration we have:

$I=\int_x^a\int_0^a\,\frac{y^2\,dx\,dy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \therefore$

$I=\int_x^a\left[y^2\,\sinh^{-1}(\frac{x}{y})\right]_0^{a}\,dy\,\therefore$

$I=\int_x^ay^2\,\sinh^{-1}(\frac{a}{y})\,dy$

A check on Wolfram Alpha shows the integral to be ugly but aside from that, the lower limit of x leaves me thinking that my final answer will involve x, whereas clearly it should not.

Thanks for any help,
Mitch.

Comment: when you change the order of integration, you also have to think about the region over which you are integrating

Comment: i would always recommend to draw a picture of ur integration domain...\

Comment: Thanks for that, it got me on the right track. I've got it now. Thanks, Mitch.

Answer (score 2):

The region of integration is $$D = \{ (x, y) \ \epsilon \ R^2 \ | \ 0 \le x \le a, x \le y \le a \} $$ See that D is both a type - I and type - II domain and thus can be projected onto the y - axis. i.e. $$D = \{ (x, y) \ \epsilon \ R^2 \ | \ 0 \le y \le a, 0 \le x \le y \} $$So swapping here connotes the following transformation of the double integral 
$$\int_0^a \left ( \int_x^a {y^2dy\over {\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}} \right ) dx = \iint_D{y^2dx dy\over {\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}} = \int_0^a \left ( \int_0^y {y^2dx\over {\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}} \right ) dy$$